# Fill arrays with random ints quickly

Tags: java, arrays

My instructor wants us to populate an array with 25,000 random variables so we can sort them.

This is the first part of his questions:

> 1. Randomly generate a data set of at least 25,000 integers (keys) [integer values within the range 1-99,000] and store the data set in
>      an integer array called unsorted_Array of size=25,000, and save
>      another copy to another array called sorted_Array of size=25,000
>      [Note: fill the two arrays in one step].

This is what i have for code:

```
Random rand1 = new Random ();

int [] unsorted_Array = new int [25000];
int [] sorted_Array = new int [25000];

for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i++)
{
    unsorted_Array[i] = rand1.nextInt(max);
    sorted_Array[i] = rand1.nextInt(max);
}
```

The problem is that it is taking forever to populate the arrays.  I was wondering if there was a way that I can generate the 25,000 integers quickly because there are more parts to this homework.

EDIT: Since I cant really explain I am just going to post what all needs to be done (Leaving out the first one cause got that figured out):

1. Use Quick-Sort  [we discussed in class – check the code from slides] to sort the data (keys)  and save the result in the sorted_Array [include in your code the sorting algorithm]

   At this point you should have 2 integer arrays, original-not sorted and the sorted array.
2. Randomly pick 100 elements (keys) from the unsorted_Array and store them in a new integer array called keys_Array. [ doing this  we make sure all keys are mostly found, and our binary search function will probably return the index]
   For each element (key) in the key_Array   you need to do the following:
   [Use arrays to store the statistical information you gather]

   1. Use the sequential search algorithm to search for the element in the unsorted_Array and record the following:

      - Record the index where the element (key) was found.
      - The time it takes to locate the element in the unsorted_Array [use the time function to calculate the time]
   2. Use the binary search algorithm to search for the element in the unsorted_Array and record the following:

      - Record the index where the element (key) was found [or  index = -1  if the result is not found]
      - The time it takes to locate [or not found] the element in the unsorted_Array
   3. Use the sequential search algorithm to search for the element in the sorted_Array and record the following:

      - Record the index where the element (key) was found [or  index = -1  if the result is not found]
      - The time it takes to locate [or not found] the element in the sorted_Array
   4. Use the binary search algorithm to search for the element in the sorted_Array and record the following:

      - Record the index where the element (key) was found [or  index = -1  if the result is not found]
      - The time it takes to locate [or not found] the element in the sorted_Array
   5. Calculate the average time (in nanoseconds - 1 second = 1 000 000 000 nanoseconds (billion)) taken by both algorithms to locate a single key in both cases, i.e. in the sorted array and in the unsorted array.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Well, your arrays aren't copies and you could eliminate half of the time with `sorted_Array[i] = unsorted_Array[i]; // rand1.nextInt(max);`

Comment: Not unless you want to start using `Thread`s

Comment: also, what @ElliottFrisch points out is a bug in your code because your professor wants you to store a COPY of the first array, and not a different set of random numbers.

Comment: Okay that solves the copy problem but it will still take a long time to compile right? Is there a faster way to populate that array?

Comment: It took 0 seconds for me (in fact it took 7 milliseconds).  There is a difference between compile time and runtime

Comment: Changed your title to something actually descriptive of your problem.

Comment: Doesn't take that long to run: http://ideone.com/yxo0QK

Comment: 0.073 seconds for me :v are you using a Turing Machine by any chance?

Comment: Okay I was wondering why the run time was so long i guess, I also need to sort those arrays using quick sort and I have the code for that

Comment: Using `sorted_Array = Arrays.copyOf(unsorted_Array, unsorted_Array.length);` and removing `sorted_Array[i] = rand1.nextInt(max);` gets me down around 3 milliseconds...

Comment: Okay but then when I need to do other things on the program like quick sort and selection sort wont the run time take forever to get to those things?

Comment: I don't think the fill process is the bottle neck. Perhaps you should consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: The code you provided is not slow. If yours is running slowly, it must be in another part that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Never mind I got it figured out, thanks for the help!!

Comment: Create the `unsorted_Array` once.  When you need a copy it, use `sorted_Array = Arrays.copyOf(unsorted_Array, unsorted_Array.length);` to copy the contents of the `unsorted_Array` to the `sorted_array`, it takes < 1 millisecond to complete, I fail to see why this is an issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int [] unsorted_Array = new int [25000];

for(int i : unsorted_Array){
    i = rand1.nextInt(max)
}

int [] sorted_Array = unsorted_Array.clone();
```

Comment: it's hardly the problem he has

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, that will reduce your time by eliminating the extra random number generation for the second array. Also, will do the copy array in 1 step for both of the array. (as stated by your instructor). In the end, you can sort the sorted_array as shown below.

```
Random rand1 = new Random ();

int [] unsorted_Array = new int [25000];
int [] sorted_Array = new int [25000];

for (int i = 0; i < 25000; i++)
{
    int newRandVal = rand1.nextInt(max);
    unsorted_Array[i] = newRandVal;
    sorted_Array[i] = newRandVal;
}
Arrays.sort(sorted_array);
```

Comment: You could just do your loop's contents in one line `unsorted_Array[i] = sorted_Array[i] = rand1.nextInt(max);`. Less code, not creating a new int each iteration...

Comment: yeah I got that part, now I am on to the sorting of the arrays

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it is taking forever to populate the arrays.

The code is pretty much optimal, and should run really fast.  (In a fraction of a second ...)  So, I suspect that the source of the slowness is actually somewhere else in your program.

Lesson: Don't jump to conclusions, especially on performance-related problems.

---

But if it *really* is slow, then the most likely (IMO) problem is that the random number generator is taking a long time to get the random seed.  That means that there is something strange with the way your operating system is collecting "entropy".  (I have seen this happen on virtual machines where the "entropy gathering" mechanisms weren't working properly due to virtualization ....)

The simple workaround is to supply a seed for the random number generator yourself; e.g.

```
Random rand1 = new Random(123456);  // or something.
```